# verticaly center align the text in a div

Tags: css

I have a div named "product-name" with 30px height & 11px font-size, It suppose to contain the product name.
If a product name is dual line it seems fine but if the product name is single line it starts from the top of the layer, I actually want it become vertically center align.

please let me know if there is any css property or trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JGGQg/

Here's a trick i've used:

```
display: table-cell; 
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: honestly curious about the downvote? I'm not a css expert, is this a bad approach?

Comment: when I arrived you were at a -1 as was the question. I'd chalk it up to "just some random ass".  Great answer, I've even deleted mine. Very clever approach.  Have you tested this across the board? Are there any issues with this in any specific browser version/platform?

Comment: @Dr. Dredel, I believe IE 7 doesn't support the display, but IE8 and every other browser supports it.

Answer (score 0):

The trick, I would use a table to vertical align. By default a table comes with that property, and it works for most browsers.

D,

Answer (score 0):

Set the line-height property to be the same as the height and then set vertical-align to middle.

```
line-height:30px;
vertical-align:middle;
```