# Positioning the image in the center of the li verticaly

Tags: html, css

I know this one has been asked few times already ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434113/verticaly-center-align-the-text-in-a-div), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796220/center-image-to-the-center-of-div)), but it seems I'm missing the point as I can't achieve this in my example. Here is the example: [jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Hitman666/aDVyu/). Thanx for your help.

HTML:

```
<li class="imageFrame">
    <a class="nyroModal" rel="gal" href="#photo_3680" title="Take a walk on the wild side ">
        <img class="" src="http://salon-cakovec.fotografija.hr/prijava/upload/thumb/fepessoa_1339763389.jpg" height="120" width="120" alt="Take a walk on the wild side">
    </a>
</li>​
```

CSS:

```
.imageFrame {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    border: 3px solid #EEE;
    background-color: #CCC;
}


.imageFrame img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/aDVyu/4/

comment - `float` and add -

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Yes! IE7 does not support display: table-cell; property

If you want this to work in IE7 also then you need to use jQuery to calculate height - http://jsfiddle.net/tQBVy/

Comment: But keep in mind it won't work with IE7- (`table-cell` not supported)

Comment: ah, float was killing the show for me :/, as I did try display: table-cell; vertical-aling: middle; as it was suggested in the link 1 i referenced. Thanks!